# Which training method is used in cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer.train?

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing a project for recognizing expressions.my plan is to use LBP and SVM.For Implementing I choose Opencv and Python.I know that there is a inbuilt function  createLBPHFaceRecognizer in opencv for LBP calculations.Which training method is used in  createLBPHFaceRecognizer.train, is it SVM or K nearest or anything else?

Comment: simple 1 nearest neighbour is used there. (and yes, an SVM will improve results !)

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a similar problem and if I was you, I would first detect face landmarks (best is DLib: http://dlib.net/webcam_face_pose_ex.cpp.html but in C++) then classify face points to get expression. They made something great in JavaScript (face landmarks, expressions classification - https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr) but it is not pretty robust in detecting face landmarks.